# Saving charts in Calc to Excel file format

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, microsoft-office

G'day,

I need to save files from Libreoffice Calc to Excel format.
My charts are not displaying correctly.
How do I make sure my charts are Excel compatible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will never be sure. Even between different Excel versions, charts can be displayed differently!

- you can minimize any "misconfiguration", using the least possible features on your chart, that is, do not put special bullets or fancy lines.
- If you want to send the charts to someone outside your company/institution, ask them to install LibreOffice. Tell them it's free!
- If the destination does not need to edit your work, send them a PDF version of the spreadsheet.